# os.walk and glob.glob return different results

Tags: python, web-scraping, filesystems, glob, os.walk

I am trying to pre-process some data for a machine learning project, where I have already cloned different repositories from GitHub, and am now working on cleaning the data to only get the Python files. I came across `os.walk` and `glob.glob`, but they seem to return a different number of files. Below are my code for each of the methods:

```
# Using os.walk
abs_paths = []
repos_path = f"{(os.path.dirname(__file__))}/repos"
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(repos_path):
        for f in filenames:
            abs_path = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            if abs_path.endswith(".py"):
                abs_paths.append(abs_path)
print(len(abs_paths)) # 10235
print(len(set(abs_path))) # 10235
```

```
# Using glob.glob
pyfiles = glob.glob(f"{(os.path.dirname(__file__))}/repos/**/*.py", recursive=True)
print(len(pyfiles)) # 10375
print(len(set(pyfile))) # 10375
```

**As a result, `os.walk` returns 10235 files, but `glob.glob` returns 10375.** When I compare the (set) difference between the two results, I see that `os.walk` does not return some files containing `/venv/` in their path, but `glob.glob` does. However, I also see that `glob.glob` does not return some files containing `/.venv/` in their path, which `os.walk` does.

For example, the following is returned by `os.walk`, but not by `glob.glob`:

`[pathtorepos]/mreyes2017/api_python_flask_apispec/.venv/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/pyparsing.py'`

Also, out of the 10375 files returned using `glob.glob`, only 8874 of them appears in the result of `os.walk`.

Therefore, I am confused by what the differences in these two methods are. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try doing `len(set(abs_paths))` and `len(set(pyfiles))`

Comment: @Matiiss I've checked that doing this returns the same number as just doing len(). But I will edit my post so this won't be asked anymore. Thanks!

Comment: I'm on Win10/cpy39/NTFS and can't reproduce this (16601 vs. 16601 .py files in my workspace).